# How do I alter a value with python script in Orange

Tags: orange

This is my first time attempting anything in Orange, but I'm completely lost looking at Tables, Domains, attributes, etc. I know it's etiquette to attempt to post some code, but even after looking at the examples I can find, I still don't have a clue. Sorry.

I have a csv file that contains several columns, one of which is a "Name" column. The names themselves are horse names followed by the country of origin in brackets, e.g. "DOBBIN(IRE)".
All I wish to do is use a Python Script to remove the country from the name, so "DOBBIN(IRE)" => "DOBBIN", and all other variables are left intact.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?